# Nested list comprehension dict and list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, which one with many keys and would like to filter only the value of the key price of each dictionary into a list. I was using the code below but not working...

```
print [b for a:b in dict.items() if a='price' for dict in data]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: for a:b  ? syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need something like following (if `data` is your "list of dicts"):

```
[d.get('price') for d in data]
```

What I am doing is, iterating over list of dicts and to each dict use `get('price')` (as `get()` doesn't throw key exception) to read value of 'price' key.
Note: Avoid to use 'dict' as a variable name as it is in-build type name.

Example:

```
>>> data = [ {'price': 2, 'b': 20}, 
             {'price': 4, 'a': 20}, 
             {'c': 20}, {'price': 6, 'r': 20} ]  # indented by hand
>>> [d.get('price') for d in data]
[2, 4, None, 6]
>>>
```

You can remove `None` in output list, by adding explicit if-check as: `[d['price'] for d in data if 'price' in d]`.

Reviews on your code:

```
[b for a:b in dict.items() if a='price' for dict in data]
```

1. You have silly syntax error `a:b` should be `a, b`
2. Second, syntax error in if condition — `a='price'` should be `a == 'price'`  (misspell == operator as =)
3. Order of nested loops are wrong (in list compression we write nested loop later)
4. This is it not an error, it is but bad practice to use inbuilt type name as variable name. You shouldn't use 'dict', 'list', 'str', etc as variable(or function) name.

   Correct form of your code is:

   ```
     [b for dict in data for a, b in dict.items() if a == 'price' ]
   ```
5. In your list compression expression `for a, b in dict.items() if a == 'price'` loop is unnecessary—simple `get(key)`, `setdefualt(key)` or `[key]` works faster without loop.

Comment: Thanks Grijesh! It is exactly that what I needed! Just to understand where my mistake was, I have tried my version with a,b instead of a:b but it did not work also... and thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user2950162 No there was other mistakes also in your code I updated my answer, you should read also so that you can avoid mistakes next time.